# XSLT - Add incrementing id attribute to the nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an xml like this,

```
<doc>
  <section>1<section>
  <section>1<section>
  <p>22</p>
  <p>22</p>
  <p>22</p>
  <footer></footer>
  <footer></footer>
  <footer></footer>
</doc>
```

what I need to do `id` add new attribute to `<footer>` nodes. 
So the output would be

```
<doc>
   <section>1<section>
   <section>1<section>
   <p>22</p>
   <p>22</p>
   <p>22</p>
   <footer id="number-1"></footer>
   <footer id="number-2"></footer>
   <footer id="number-3"></footer>
 </doc>
```

I can add new attribute to `<footer`> node but the problem I'm facing is add incrementing ids in XSLT.

```
<xsl:template match="footer">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="'number-'[position()]"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I've tried to use xsl variable but since it's cannot change like other languages i couldn't do it. also I tried with `position()`  function but it only gives position of the current node.so i this case id numbers stating from 6.

can you suggest me an solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: you could use `<xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="'number-'"/><xsl:number level="any"/></xsl:attribute>`

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen Please add your comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use

```
<xsl:attribute name="id">
    <xsl:value-of select="'number-'"/>
    <xsl:number level="any"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```